# Override methods in dynamic form

Tags: axapta, x++

Is there any way to override method in dynamic form?

I've created a form from code (create Form, adding DataSource, etc. and then FormRun). The problem is with the datasource validation. In normal form (in the AOT) I'd use `return true` in validateWrite to prevent normal validation on table.

How I can achieve this only from code? (or more precisely: when I've only class to play with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [FormBuild.addMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa598821%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) is what you are looking for. Provide the `FormBuildDatasource` object as the third argument to the `addMethod` method.

Comment: Not quite... `addMethod` need `TreeNode` but dataSource is `FormBuildDatasource` that is not compatible...
But I go from `form` (which cast to `TreeNode`) and after bunch of `AOTfindChild` use **AOTsetSource**. Thx for direction